# A position fixed child div is ignoring right side padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centre align text in a div like this

```
.profile-title{
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

it is inside a container with 30px of padding

```
 .content { 
    padding: 30px;
 };
```

but *.profile-title* is ignoring the right side padding

[image: full width of the screen]

[image: padding]

why is .profile-title being pushed 30px over on the left side?

Comment: The property `position:fixed` takes the element out of the flow on the document and now is positioned in relation to the Viewport ...  Therefore there is no padding to keep. The element is no more inside `content`.

Comment: Did you try something like `padding: 0 30px;` in `.profile-title`? Or `width: 100%-30px;`?

Comment: @wtmcm - I believe you are switching the words *left* and *right*

Comment: The padding is making the width actually 100% + 60px.